# Polygon onclick event problem with its shape

Tags: javascript, svg, polygon

I've build a square surround it by 4 polygon (trapezium shape) I need to change its colors in a sequence by clicking on it.

I couldn't find any similar problem over the web.
but i did try changing `zIndex` on mouse over and out but it wasnt a good solution.

The problem you can check here https://jsfiddle.net/d9Lh31sv/1/
Even as a polygon html shows it like a rectangle and they´re are over each other on its sides as you see on this image  [image: Focus]

Wondering if there is a way that the click event can respect only its polygon limit..
Thanks in advance.

```js
 var objTrapezium = document.getElementsByClassName('trapezium'); 
 if (objTrapezium) {  
  for (var i = 0; i < objTrapezium.length; i++) {
   objTrapezium[i].onclick = function() {
    var _Color = this.firstChild.nextSibling.attributes.fill.value; 
    _Color = _Color=="none"  ? "grey" :  _Color =="grey" ? "red":  _Color =="red" ? "green": _Color =="green" ?"blue": _Color =="blue" ? "grey": "";       
    this.firstChild.nextSibling.attributes.fill.value = _Color;
        
   };

   objTrapezium[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.zIndex = 9999;
    this.style.backgroundColor = "lightsteelblue";
     }
   objTrapezium[i].onmouseout = function(){
    this.style.zIndex = 1;
    this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
     }


  }

 }
```

```css
.trapezium{
 position: relative;
}
.square{
  left: 202px;
  width: 73px;
  height: 73px;
  top: 102px;
}
.bottom{
  left: 53px;
  top: 175px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.left{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: -243px;
  top: 102px;
}
.right{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  left: -315px;
  top: 101px;
}
.top{
 transform: rotate(-180deg);
 left: 129px;
 top: -48px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg class="trapezium square">
    <rect stroke="black" fill="none" width="73" height="73" />    
  </svg>
  <svg class="trapezium bottom" height="72" width="217">
    <polygon stroke="black" fill="none" points="0,72 72,0 144,0 216,72" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="trapezium left" height="72" width="217">
    <polygon stroke="black" fill="none" points="0,72 72,0 144,0 216,72" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="trapezium right" height="72" width="217">
    <polygon stroke="black" fill="none" points="0,72 72,0 144,0 216,72" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="trapezium top" height="72" width="217">
    <polygon stroke="black" fill="none" points="0,72 72,0 144,0 216,72" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I would do this differently: I would put everything in one svg element. Also you are trying to set the `background-color`. In SVG you need to set the `fill` instead

Comment: I did `background-color` that just to show that they over each other...

Answer (score 2):

As I've commented I would do this differently:  I would put everything in one svg element.
Please take a look. Maybe this is what you need.

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:300px}
use{fill:white;}
use:hover{fill:gold}
```

```html
 <svg viewBox="-115 -115 230 230">
    <defs>
      <polygon id="poly" stroke="black"  points="-36.5,36.5 36.5,36.5 108, 108 -108,108 -36.5,36.5" transform="translate(0,3)"  />
    </defs>

    <use xlink:href="#poly" />
    <use xlink:href="#poly" transform="rotate(90)" /> 
    <use xlink:href="#poly" transform="rotate(180)" />
    <use xlink:href="#poly" transform="rotate(270)" />
    
    <rect stroke="black" fill="none" x="-35" y="-35" width="70" height="70" /> 
    
  </svg>
```

Comment: It definitely looks better! Gonna try to adapt it for what I need, I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately I wasn't able to adapt your code. @exaneta, Anyhow to a better understanding, this draw its gointo to part of an odontogram exam, and represents all 5 parts of a tooth, so I need to paint each one individually in 5 stages/colors. I do appreciate your help lef me know if you have any other suggestion. this is what I found using css and js http://jsfiddle.net/yamidvo/quvp3/4/

Answer (score 0):

The solution I could come out with is by using the `offsetX` and `offsetY` on `js` to find out if the click is out of trapezium range, then use some logic to change the colors  in the right element.

```js
var objTrapezium = document.getElementsByClassName('trapezium');
if (objTrapezium) {
  for (var i = 0; i < objTrapezium.length; i++) {
    objTrapezium[i].onclick = function(e) {
      var id = this.attributes.id.value;
      var x = e.offsetX;
      var y = e.offsetY;
      var height = this.attributes.height.value;
      var outLeft = (y + x) < height;
      var outRight = (x - y) > (height * 2);
      var nextElemetId = "";
      var _Color = "";
      if ((id !== "square") && (outLeft || outRight)) {
        switch (id) {
          case "top":
            nextElemetId = outRight ? "left" : "right";
            break
          case "right":
            nextElemetId = outRight ? "top" : "bottom";
            break
          case "bottom":
            nextElemetId = outRight ? "right" : "left";
            break
          case "left":
            nextElemetId = outRight ? "bottom" : "top";
            break
        }
        var objNextTrapezium = document.getElementById(nextElemetId);
        _Color = objNextTrapezium.firstChild.nextSibling.attributes.fill.value;
        _Color = _Color == "none" ? "grey" : _Color == "grey" ? "red" : _Color == "red" ? "green" : _Color == "green" ? "blue" : _Color == "blue" ? "grey" : "none";
        objNextTrapezium.firstChild.nextSibling.attributes.fill.value = _Color;

      } else {
        _Color = this.firstChild.nextSibling.attributes.fill.value;
        _Color = _Color == "none" ? "grey" : _Color == "grey" ? "red" : _Color == "red" ? "green" : _Color == "green" ? "blue" : _Color == "blue" ? "grey" : "none";
        this.firstChild.nextSibling.attributes.fill.value = _Color;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

```css
.trapezium {
 position: relative;
}

#square {
 left: 199px;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    top: 101px;
}

#top {
 transform: rotate(180deg);
 left: 51px;
 top: 29px;
}

#right {
 transform: rotate(270deg);
 left: -98px;
 top: 101px;
}

#bottom {
 left: 127px;
 top: 96px; 
}

#left {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
    left: -165px;
    top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="trapezium" id="square" width="72" height="72">
  <rect stroke="black" fill="none" width="72" height="72" />    
</svg>
<svg class="trapezium" id="top" height="72" width="216">
  <polygon stroke="black" fill="none" points="0,72 72,0 144,0 216,72" />
</svg>
<svg class="trapezium" id="right" height="72" width="216">
  <polygon stroke="black" fill="none" points="0,72 72,0 144,0 216,72" />
</svg>
<svg class="trapezium" id="bottom" height="72" width="216">
  <polygon stroke="black" fill="none" points="0,72 72,0 144,0 216,72" />
</svg>   
<svg class="trapezium" id="left" height="72" width="216">
  <polygon stroke="black" fill="none" points="0,72 72,0 144,0 216,72" />
</svg>
```